# JavaScript: Get query string from URL with routing that uses # sign

Tags: javascript, extjs, query-string, extjs5, window.location

I'm using Ext JS's [routing](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.util.History) in my app, but this is a more fundamental question... just know that routing in Ext JS is set up like `http://url/#area1/subarea1`, where #area1 will take me to the parent level area, and subarea1 will take me to area1's 1st child item.

Anyway, what I'm trying to accomplish is adding query params to my URL... so it would be something like `http://url/#area1/subarea1?startDate=03/03/2014&isDraft=true`, but it looks like [`location.search`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript) is an empty string, in both FF and Chrome, so I'm assuming that's by design.  I know I can parse location.href, but that seems silly.  I'm basically wondering if I'm doing something wrong, or if there's some other property I can use?

Comment: The [ExtJS Routing Guide](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/application_architecture/router.html) demonstrates how parameterized URLs can be handled by the framework.

Comment: Not really what I'm looking for... doesn't look like they deal with query strings at all, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Query strings belong **before** the fragment as per the spec. You can define whatever scheme you want for managing data after the hash but why re-invent the wheel? The question was tagged `extjs` and the framework has a good API for working with fragment URI / routing.  It's not clear what you're trying to achieve that can't be accomplished by following the examples in the link?

Comment: @Emissary because there's not a clear way of doing it... in your link, I didn't see a mention of a query string, and yes, you're right, the spec says to have it before the hash, but it doesn't seem relatively straightforward on how to put it before the hash without doing some URL massaging.  I have a fairly quick solution that I came up with, and I'll eventually get around to posting it.

Answer (score 1):

A location URL always has the following order: protocol hostname pathname search hash. In your case, search is empty because the `#` is before the first `?`.

So, in `http://url/#area1/subarea1?startDate=03/03/2014&isDraft=true`,

- `location.protocol` is `http:`
- `location.hostname` is `url`
- `location.pathname` is `/`
- `location.search` is empty
- `location.hash` is `#area1/subarea1?startDate=03/03/2014&isDraft=true`

So `location.hash.split('?')[1]` should contain the "query params" you want, or if you want them as an object, `Ext.Object.fromQueryString(location.hash.split('?')[1] || {})`.

Comment: Is there an RFC or some sort of documentation on the URL order you specified?  I'd be interested to read that.

Comment: This faster and uses less memory: `Ext.Object.fromQueryString(location.hash.replace(/^.+\?/, ''))`. See benchmark: https://jsperf.com/hash-replace-vs-split#area1/subarea1?startDate=03/03/2014&isDraft=true

Answer (score 0):

I just came across the same issue in Angular. Here was my solution:

```
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    url = url.toLowerCase(); 
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&").toLowerCase();
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```